# If operator '?' in Python?

Tags: python

Python has an if operator '?' like Java?

Example in Java:

```java
String res = (2 > 1) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Python doesn't have `?:` operator but `if`/`else` can be used to achieve the same result on one line:

```
res = 'yes' if 2 > 1 else 'no'
```

Comment: We can even use `res = ('no', 'yes')[2 > 1]`